# How to use php _GET?

Tags: php, javascript

I am asking two things.

1. The first question is am I doing this correctly? I am putting together a link with javascript variables

   ```
   http://google.com/test.php?var="+class4
   ```

   And then I am using php to get the values of the variables from the URL
2. Can I use a link at all to do the variables or must I use a button? When using the link nothing shows in the url after the `?`.

Comment: You have to provide more code.... nothing can be said if we don't know more about the context.

Comment: It looks vaguely correct - if it was part of a longer expression to concatenate a string. Building links like that is an option (often needs `encodeURI` though) and alternative to form submitting. There's an issue in your remaining code perhaps. Show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the link you'd need to do something like

```
var link = "http://google.com/test.php?class=" + "class4";
```

To go there you would do something like

```
location.href = link;
```

And in the PHP code to get the value, you would do something like

```
$class = $_GET['class'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Link should look like http://google.com/test.php?var=class4 (There is no need for quotes or +)

then you can do `echo $_GET['var'];`

Comment: i assumed the + was javascript concat

Comment: i'm not sure if he meant that as a javascript string, if it was, then yes, + is used for concatenating.

Answer (score 1):

hmm what dou you get out of this :

```
var url = 'http://google.com/test.php?var='+class4;
alert(url);
```

Assuming 'class4' is an variable in javascript you have created. otherwise

```
var url = 'http://google.com/test.php?var=class4';
alert(url);
```

Does this give you the url you are wanting to redirect to ?

if so try to copy paste the alert from the alert into the browsers adresbar and test if it works

in the php page just after